# error 0x501 trying add RelowableControl to my view android

Tags: android

Please may someone help me...
am trying to follow Skyepub tutotial but when i try to add the RelowableControl in my view for read Epub. i get errors and my emulator shutdown with theses errors.

```
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM//GLEScmImp.cpp:glHint:1069 error 0x500
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM//GLEScmImp.cpp:glColorPointer:433 error 0x501
../../sdk/emulator/opengl//host/libs/Translator/GLES_CM//GLEScmImp.cpp:glColorPointer:433 error 0x501
```

Comment: Look at this thread, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82997 I'm having the same error, I know it is a different instance because on the thread they point an issue with the Google Maps API, but it seems related to the same emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following one of the advices in the mailthread linked by GhostDerfel, I got rid of a very similar problem by installing a x86_64 image of the emulator[image: AVD X86_64]